# Not able to connect to EC2 instance in AWS via python/psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, psycopg2

I am having trouble connecting to aws via python.  I have a macOSX operating system.

What i did:

1. I created an ec2 instance and chose an operating system (ubuntu) and downloaded postgresssql in the remote server.  Then i created securitygroups where i added the following configuration:
   type:
   ssh
   protocol:
   tcp
   port: 22
   source: custom, 0.0.0.0/0

Then i added another rule:
postgresql
TCP
5432
custom
my_computer_ip_address 71.???.??.???/32

where i added question marks just to hide the address.  but its in that format.

Now, aws had me create a .pem file in order to query from the database.  I downloaded this pem file into a secret location.
When i go to my local machine, go to my terminal and type:
ssh -i "timescale.pem" ubuntu@ec2-??-???-??-???.compute-1.amazonaws.com"

i am able to connect.  I also went to my dbeaver and created a new connection and set up a connection where i am using an ssh tunnel and a public key to read the 'timescale.pem' file i created.  I then go to main and type my username and password:
username: postgres
database: example
password: mycustompassword

and i am able to connect with no issues.

Now, when I go to python with psycopg2 library, i am just unable to connect at all.  I have gone through all the examples here in stackoverflow and none of them have helped me.  Heres what i am using to connect to aws from python:

```
path_to_secret_key = os.path.expanduser("~/timescale.pem")
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    dbname='example',
    user='postgres',
    password='pass123',
    host='ec2-??-??-??-???.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
    port='22',
    sslmode='verify-full',
    sslrootcert=path_to_secret_key)
```

I then get this error:

```
connection to server at "ec2-34-???-??-???.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (34.201.??.???), port 22 failed: could not read root certificate file "/Users/me/timescale.pem": no certificate or crl found
```

Ok...then i switched ports and added '5432' and get this warning:

```
connection to server at "ec2-??-???-??-???.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (34.???.??.212), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

When i ssh into my terminal and type: netstat -nl |grep 5432 i get the following:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     812450   /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432

Can someone please help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `.pem` file is for connecting to the EC2 instance over SSH, on port `22`. PostgreSQL is running on port `5432`. You don't use the `.pem` file for database connections, only for `ssh` connections. You need to change your Python script to use `port='5432',` to connect directly to the PostgreSQL service running on the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work now:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
mypkey = paramiko.Ed25519Key.from_private_key_file(path_to_secret_key)
tunnel = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('remote_public_port', 22),
    ssh_username='ubuntu',
    ssh_pkey=mypkey,
    remote_bind_address=('localhost', 5432))
tunnel.start()

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    dbname='example_db',
    user='postgres',
    password='secret123',
    host='127.0.0.1',
    port=tunnel.local_bind_port)
```